# Playing multiple audio files in a row

Tags: ios, swift

I set the 4 UIButtons on the Main StoryBoard.

I would like "Button4" to implement the method of the other three Buttons in a row. (At first, plays an audio file and set selected "Button1" then "Button2" then "Button3")

However "Button2" and "Button3" are played at same time.

```
            fileprivate var player1:AVAudioPlayer?
            fileprivate var player2:AVAudioPlayer?
            fileprivate var player3:AVAudioPlayer?

            let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
            let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")
            let url3 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music3.mp3")

            @IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
                Player(url: url1)
            }

            @IBAction func pushButton2(sender: UIButton) {
                Player1(url: url2)
            }

            @IBAction func pushButton3(_ sender: UIButton) {
                Player2(url: url1, url2: url2, url3: url3)
            }


            func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
                if (player === player1) {
                    yourButton.isSelected = false
                } else if (player === player2) {
                    yourButton2.isSelected = false
                } else if (player === player3) {
                    yourButton.isSelected = false
                    player2!.play()
                    yourButton2.isSelected = true
                    player2!.play()
                    yourButton3.isSelected = true
                    player1!.play()
                }
            }

            func Player(url: URL) {
                do {
                    try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                    player1!.play()
                    yourButton.isSelected = true
                    player1!.delegate = self
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            func Player1(url: URL) {
                do {
                    try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                    player2!.play()
                    yourButton2.isSelected = true
                    player2!.delegate = self

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            func Player2(url: URL, url2: URL, url3: URL) {
                do {
                    try player3 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                    try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2)
                    try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url3)
                    player3!.play()
                    yourButton.isSelected = true
                    player3!.delegate = self
                    player2!.delegate = self
                    player1!.delegate = self
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

Comment: You said, by pressing button 4, the other buttons functions must be implemented in a row. That means each audio file should be played in a row. If this is what you're looking for, please check my answer and let me know if you face any problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you press button 4, player 1 should be played first, after that player 2 and after that player 3. For this task, the below code should work.

```
let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")
let url3 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music3.mp3")

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if (player === player1) {
        yourButton.isSelected = false
        yourButton2.isSelected = true
        do {
           //initialise player 2
           player2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2)
           player2!.delegate = self 
        }catch {

        }
        player2!.play()
    } else if (player === player2) {
        yourButton3.isSelected = true
        yourButton2.isSelected = false
        do {
           //initialise player 3
           player3 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url3) 
           player3!.delegate = self 
        }catch {

        }
        player3!.play()
    } else if (player === player3) {
        yourButton3.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but only player1 is played.

Comment: It looks like player2, player 3 are not initialized with audio files. once you do that, they will be played. Let me edit my answer

Comment: @risa8, I updated it with the variables you are using

Comment: umm I still receive error "arguments labels (url) do not match any available overloads"

Comment: @risa8, some problem with initialisation. rectified it now

Comment: @risa8, did you have this line in your button 4 function `player1!.delegate = self`